# What's the "cost" of completing the Grimm troupe ritual

Tags: hollow-knight

Various characters throughout the game hint that there's some terrible cost of completing the ritual.

From Brumm: " if you return to the Master and complete the Ritual... Mrmm. As long as you do it without regret, I will bear you no hatred. "

From Jiji: "Assisting them might benefit you, but who knows what suffering it may cause? "

What ominous cost are they alluding to?

Comment: According to the wiki: "The Ritual performed by the Grimm Troupe is designed to sustain the Nightmare's Heart with a new vessel once the old one dies."